How to remove multiple registry values matching a string with spaces?
Dose anyone know how to remove multiple registry values matching a string with spaces?
I found a code that can do that without spaces, but I was unable to find anything that can do it when the value has spaces in it.
Works if value has no spaces.
For /f "tokens=1,*" %%k in ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\testkey" 2^>NUL ^| Find /i "0.3200.0"') do ECHO Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\testkey" /v "%%k" /f

Reg Query output:
   TestValueToRemoveWithoutSpaces,0.3200.0,es,b03f5f7f11d50a3a       REG_BINARY      F2243A58D787DA01
   Test Value To Remove With Spaces,0.3200.0,es,b03f5f7f11d50a3a       REG_BINARY      F2243A58D787DA01


The frst thing you need to do is to esure that you are running the batch file, and/or cmd.exe instance, elevated, which is a necessity for modifying or deleting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, (HKLM), entries. If you are not please try again, and [Edit] your question to provide such clarification.

I would advise that you get some assistance from PowerShell in identifying each of those matching values for deletion.
This is very similar to my answer earlier this week. The main difference being the use of the -Like operator, rather than using -Match, (which would see some of your characters as special in its regex pattern matching).
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "RegRoot=HKLM"
Set "RegKey=\SOFTWARE\testkey"
Set "ValStr=,0.3200.0,"

For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command
 "(Get-ItemProperty -Path '%RegRoot%:%RegKey%').PSObject.Properties"
 " | Where-Object Name -Like '*%ValStr%*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name"
 2^>NUL') Do %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "%RegRoot%%RegKey%" /V "%%G" /F 1>NUL

Please note, for robustness, I took the liberty of including the known leading and trailing commas in your value string.

Thanks. But PowerShell is not an option, I have to go full old school on that one. :-)

The following batch file executed with run as administrator could be used for the binary registry value deletion task:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe (set "REGEXE=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe") else set "REGEXE=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe"
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('%REGEXE% QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\testkey" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "0.3200.0"') do (
    set "RegLine=%%G"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "NameValue="!RegLine:   REG_BINARY  =" "!""
    if not "!NameValue:REG_BINARY=!" == "!NameValue!" set "NameValue="!RegLine:    REG_BINARY    =" "!""
    for %%H in (!NameValue!) do if defined NameValue %REGEXE% DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\testkey" /f /v %%H 1>nul & set "NameValue="
    endlocal
)
endlocal

ATTENTION: There must be a horizontal tab character in the batch file left and right to first REG_BINARY in seventh line and not spaces as the web browser displays and copies according to HTML specification.
The FOR /F command line results in assigning each line output by reg.exe and filtered by find.exe with leading normal spaces and horizontal tabs removed from the line to the specified loop variable G as long as the registry value name does not start with a semicolon.
In other words the environment variable RegLine is defined for the two lines with:
TestValueToRemoveWithoutSpaces,0.3200.0,es,b03f5f7f11d50a3a    REG_BINARY    F2243A58D787DA01
Test Value To Remove With Spaces,0.3200.0,es,b03f5f7f11d50a3a    REG_BINARY    F2243A58D787DA01

There are either four normal spaces or a horizontal tab left and right to REG_BINARY. That is used next after setting up a new local environment with enabled delayed variable expansion.
The environment variable NameValue is redefined with inserting at the beginning " and replacing REG_BINARY with a horizontal tab before and after it by " " and appending one more " at the end. The string value assigned to NameValue on value name separated with a horizontal tab from value type and value type separated with a horizontal tab from registry value after this command line is:
"TestValueToRemoveWithoutSpaces,0.3200.0,es,b03f5f7f11d50a3a" "F2243A58D787DA01"
"Test Value To Remove With Spaces,0.3200.0,es,b03f5f7f11d50a3a" "F2243A58D787DA01"

The following IF condition checks if the substitution of REG_BINARY surrounded by horizontal tabs really worked. If the string value of NameValue still contains REG_BINARY, one more substitution with four spaces before and after REG_BINARY is run to define the environment variable NameValue with the value name enclosed in " and with the registry value enclosed in ".
A FOR loop is used for processing the two double quoted strings assigned to the environment variable NameValue.
REG with the command for deletion of the value of which name is assigned with the surrounding " to loop variable H is run on first execution with still defined environment variable NameValue. Then the environment variable NameValue is deleted with set "NameValue=".
The environment variable NameValue is not defined anymore on second execution of the command line with "F2243A58D787DA01" assigned to the loop variable H. The Windows commands REG and SET are not executed anymore for that reason due to the false evaluated IF condition.
Finally the initial environment before enabling delayed variable expansion is restored before processing the next line for avoiding a stack overflow on many registry values to delete. Read this answer for details about the commands SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

echo /?
endlocal /?
for /?
if /?
reg /?
reg delete /?
reg query /?
set /?
setlocal /?

See also single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file for an explanation of the unconditional command operator &.
Read the Microsoft documentation about Using command redirection operators for an explanation of 2>nul and |. The redirection operators > and | must be escaped with caret character ^ on FOR command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command FOR which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background with %ComSpec% /c and the command line within ' appended as additional arguments.
This batch file executes on 64-bit Windows always 64-bit reg.exe even on batch file processed by 32-bit %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe.

After playing around with the code a bit more. I noticed that when I output the "Reg Query" to a text file that only the beginning of the output line has 4 spaces and everything else is separated by tabs. -_- So after this new discovery I gave it another go and came up with a script that can do this including removing the Reg Keys.
Important: If you copy and paste this code then the "delims=" entry will be 2 small spaces. You need to replace this 2 small spaces with a TAB space.
    @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
    Set "RegDelSearch=0.3200.0"
    Set "RegPath=HKLM\SOFTWARE\testkey"
    For /f "tokens=1,* delims=  " %%a in ('Reg Query "%RegPath%" 2^>NUL ^| FindStr /l /i "%RegDelSearch%"') do  (
        Set "RegData=%%a"
        SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
        ECHO.!RegData!| FindStr /r /b /c:"HKEY_.*"
        If !ErrorLevel! equ 0 (
            Reg Delete "!RegData!" /f 1>NUL
        ) Else (
            Reg Delete "%RegPath%" /v "!RegData:~4!" /f 1>NUL
        )
        ENDLOCAL
    )
    ENDLOCAL


If for some reason PowerShell is not available, you could possibly fall back on a WMI based solution.
This one uses WMIC.exe:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "RegRoot=&H80000001"
Set Set "RegKey=SOFTWARE\testkey"
Set "ValStr=,0.3200.0,"

Set "WMICmd=%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe"

For /F "Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%WMICmd% Class StdRegProv Call EnumValues
 "%RegRoot%"^, "%RegKey%"') Do For /F "Delims=" %%J In ('For %%I In (%%H^) Do
 @Set /P "=%%I" 0^<NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%ValStr%"') Do (
    Set "_=%%J" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    %WMICmd% Class StdRegProv^
     Call DeleteValue "%RegRoot%", "%RegKey%", "!_:\\=\!" 1>NUL & EndLocal)

Here, &H80000001 is the appropriate representation for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
